# Iterating through Object (data) - Angular

Tags: angular

Below is my code and what i am trying to do is subscribe to the data i return after the send function is triggered. Now after subscribing, i assign the data return from my API to the this.Data to pass on to my ngFor to display the my data. But i get the error `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'`. Could it be i am not reaching the display property in the data or not accepting the data in the right format (object)?

```
Data: DataLink[] = [];


        Send(){

                this.http.forward(this.info)
                 .subscribe( data => {

                     this.Data = data;


                       console.log(data);
                 }) }

    <div *ngFor="let msg of Data">

      {{msg.display}}


**response**
 data: Array
    0: Object
       display: "How are you?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop on the keys directly. you should be fine

```
Send(){

                this.http.forward(this.info)
                 .subscribe( data => {

              Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {

                  this.Data = data[key];

                       console.log(data);
                 }) }

    <div *ngFor="let msg of Data">

      {{msg.display}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing happens because `data` is an object and `ngFor` requires an array.

take a look at this answer: [Error trying to diff '[object Object]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216857/error-trying-to-diff-object-object)

Also, see this for angular `http` service doc/examples https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: am i accessing the display response rightly tho please?

Comment: whta's `forward`? more importantly what is `this.http` ?

Comment: forward is a function in my service.ts

Comment: I assume it calls angular's `http` service `get`, `post` ...etc. If that's the case, and you are getting the response you expect from your REST api, then yes, you are doing it correctly. Also, see this for `http` service doc/examples https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html