# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff for array of object

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm getting this `error` for `array` of `object`. My `data` is coming from `database` so I cannot change the format of the data.

Here is what my data looks like (coming from database):

```
dataFromDatabase:any;

this.dataFromDatabase = [
  {"startTime":"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00","endTime":"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00","user_id":"148"},
  {"startTime":"Thu Oct 19 2017 12:00:00","endTime":"Thu Oct 19 2017 12:00:00","user_id":"148"},
  {"startTime":"Fri Oct 20 2017 12:00:00","endTime":"Fri Oct 20 2017 12:00:00","user_id":"148"}
];
```

What I'm doing in template:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let times of dataFromDatabase">
    <p>{{times.startTime}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code working for me man!

Comment: i'm getting this `error`  `ERROR Error: Error trying to diff `

Comment: make sure that your service call returns the array of object i think its returning objects only

Comment: the above `object` is `console.log()`  of the result from my `service`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216857/error-trying-to-diff-object-object  and @ArunKumaresh mentioned your response is object{} , like `{respone:[{"startTime":"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00","endTime":"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00","user_id":"148"},..]}` could you check web dev tool

Comment: Change this: `"startTime":"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00"` into: `startTime:"Wed Oct 18 2017 12:00:00"`. If you get the data from an service use `JSON.parse(this.dataFromDatabase)`. Or use `{{times["startTime"]}}` in template.

Comment: @Swoox , Thanks It worked for me... Thank you very much....

Comment: @GouthamGgs your welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is because *ngFor expects an array but you might be getting an object from the API.Check your response and let me know if there is any other issue.